# Angular RouterStateSnapshot params is empty when using useHash: true

Tags: angular, angular-routing, url-parameters, angular-router-guards

I'm accessing the URL parameters of my Angular 4 app using `RouterStateSnapshot` and it works just fine:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    // state.root.queryParams will hold my URL parameters
}
```

the problem is that as soon as I edit my `RouterModule` configuration and set `useHash: true` the code above stops workings for some reasons because `state.root.queryParams` will always be null.

Why is it that? How to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue - did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: not yet, otherwise I would have posted it

Comment: Thanks -- I wound up needing to reformat parameters in order to make them work.  So, "mysite/path?param=value" wound up needing to be "mysite/path/#/?param=value".  I'm not thrilled with the way the hash strategy is working, but I can't get path-strategy routing to work correctly for me right now, and this will have to do.